# How to avoid closing the popup when I select an image from the gallery?

Tags: android, dialog, popup

I'm writing an android app which adds a post with image and description. To do this I have created a poup that facilitates adding the post:

```
dialogAddPost = new Dialog(this);
dialogAddPost.setContentView(R.layout.popup_add_post);
Objects.requireNonNull(dialogAddPost.getWindow()).setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialogAddPost.getWindow().setLayout(Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Toolbar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
dialogAddPost.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.TOP;
```

Through the popup it is possible to add an image through this intent:

```
Intent iGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
iGallery.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(iGallery, REQUESCODE);
```

The problem arises when the user chooses "Open image from gallery" instead of recent images. In fact, after choosing the image, the app refreshes and the popup is closed. By clicking again on "Add Post", the post reopens and the info entered before disappear (except image). How to avoid closing the popup?

**UPDATE**

Replacing `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` with `Intent.ACTION_PICK` solves the problem. But on the internet I read that ACTION_PICK is not recommended, while ACTION_GET_CONTENT is more modern and better supported. Advice on this?

Comment: Yes, Android OS can close your activitry at any time if it is not topmost activity. You have to use onSaveInstanceState() to save the state so you can recreate the state when onCreate() is called again with its parameter not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); which will not close the dialog if you touch outside of the dialog.

Something like,

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: This is not what I need. I have to make sure that the app doesn't refresh when I select an image from the gallery.